# insert multiple row codeigniter

Tags: arrays, codeigniter

can somebody help me, im trying to insert data in 2 tables in one form using codeigniter. but, my problem is, the data are not inserted correctly. maybe because of my array because i want my data insert with add dynamically input. please help me

```
Table questions_bank:
    q_id    int(11) AutoIncrement
    id  int(11)         
    type    varchar(100)
    q_text  varchar(200)

Table answer:
    a_id    int(11) AutoIncrement
    id  int(11) 
    q_id    int(11)     
    a_text       varchar
```

**my controller:** question.php

```
function questions_data() 
  {
    $data = array(
    'q_id' => $this->input->post('q_id'),
    'id' => $this->input->post('id'),
    'type' => $this->input->post('type'),
    'q_text' => $this->input->post('q_text')
     );

    $data_answer = array(
     //'q_id' => $this->input->post('q_id'),
     'id' => $this->input->post('id'),
      'a_text'    => $this->input->post('a_text[]'),
    );

    $this->questions_data->questions($data,$data_answer);
    redirect('question/insert');
    }
```

**model:** questions_data.php

```
public function questions()
 {

  $data=array(
    'q_id'=>$this->input->post('q_id'),
    'id'=>$this->input->post('id'),
    'type'=>$this->input->post('type'),
    'q_text'=>$this->input->post('q_text'),
  );

   $data_answer = array(
   'id' => $this->input->post('id'),
  );   

  $this->db->insert('questions_bank',$data);
  $data_answer['q_id'] = $this->db->insert_id();
 $this->db->insert('answer',$data_answer);

  foreach($_POST['a_text1'] as $a_text1)
  {

    $this->db->insert('answer',$a_text1);
  }
  }
```

my view: **insert.php**

```
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Course</label>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                        <?php
                        $query = "SELECT * FROM course"; $result = mysql_query($query); ?> 
                        <select name="id" class="form-control m-b"><?php while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) { ?> 
                        <option value=" <?php echo $line['id'];?> "> <?php echo $line['Topics'];?></option> <?php } ?>
                        </select>
                        </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="line line-dashed b-b line-lg pull-in"></div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Type</label>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                        <select name="type" class="form-control m-b">
                        <option value="Easy">Easy</option>
                        <option value="Intermidiate">Intermidiate</option>
                        <option value="Hard">Hard</option>
                        </select>
                        </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="line line-dashed b-b line-lg pull-in"></div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Question</label>
                        <div class="col-md-5">
                        <input type="text" name="q_text" id="q_text" class="form-control" />
                        </div>
                        </div>

                        <div id="box">
                        <div class="line line-dashed b-b line-lg pull-in"></div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Answer</label>
                        <div class="col-md-5">
                        <input name="a_text1[' + i +'][a_text]" type="text" id="name" class="form-control"></div>


                        <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/add/add.png" width="32" height="32" border="0" align="top" class="add" id="add" />
                        </div></div></div>

                       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-default">Submit</button
```

i have attach the image of result here

[image]

**script for multiple rows**

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

  $('#add').click(function(){

    var inp = $('#box');


    var i = $('input').size() ;

    $('<div id="box' + i +'"><div class="form-group"><label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Answer</label><div class="col-md-5"><input type="text" id="name' + i+ '" class="form-control" name="a_text1[' + i +'][a_text]" /></div><img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/add/remove.png" align="top" class="add" id="remove" /></div></div></div>').appendTo(inp);

    i++;


  });
```

Comment: You should not pass any arguments while calling $this->questions_data->questions()

Comment: And also you don't need to declare $data and $data_array in controller

Comment: Your form course filed is shown with name `id`, you are manually passing `$this->input->post('id')` to the update Array, where the course id is being stored as id for your table. You seem confused with what you are doing.

Comment: can you share your DB Schema ??

Comment: @AngryCoder yes, you are right, im really confuse now and new with codeigniter. my DB 

Table questions_bank:
 q_id int(11) AutoIncrement
 id int(11)   
 type varchar(100)
 q_text varchar(200)

Table answer:
 a_id int(11) AutoIncrement
 id int(11) 
 q_id int(11)  
 a_text       varchar

Comment: i have edit my question, please help me

Comment: why do you have an `id` column in both the tables ?  What are you storing in those columns ?

Comment: the id is from other table name course.. @AngryCoder

Answer (score 0):

```
//Note: Please change your model function with the below function and when the form is submitted the form values will be posted to controller not to the model you to just pass it to the model function that all.
public function questions($data,$data_answer)
{

  $this->db->insert('questions_bank',$data);
  $data_answer['q_id'] = $this->db->insert_id();
  $this->db->insert('answer',$data_answer);
  //Note: For loop case just pass the array from the controller and use it in model 
  //foreach($_POST['a_text1'] as $a_text1)
  //{

    //$this->db->insert('answer',$a_text1);
  //}
}
```

Comment: thankyou for your help, actually i need to use a_text1 because i want to insert my certain data using add dynamically input, i have edit my question, please take a look. sorry for inconvinient :) @rahul sharma